# jQuery can't submit form that was loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I used jQuery to load a form from sidebar to the main page. Now I want to use jQuery to submit this form, but I am having difficulty doing that. I have used the same jQuery code to submit a form that was not loaded with jQuery. Hopefully someone can see what I did wrong.

How can I modify the following code so it will submit my form?

**LINK THAT LOADED THE FORM:**

```
<a href="#" id="link1">Exam1</a>
```

**JQUERY THAT LOADED FORM:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#link1').click(function(){
        $('#show').load('exam.php');

    });     
});
```

**FORM:**

```
<form action="form.php" id="exam" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="new_exam"/>
    <button id="sub" name="" style="color:#e75618; padding:5px 66px" class="btn btn-default" ><b>Add Exam</b></button>
</form>
```

**JQUERY TO SUBMIT FORM:**

```
$("#sub").click( function() {
    $.post( $("#exam").attr("action"), $("#exam").serialize(), function(info){ $("#result").html(info); } );
    clearInput();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    });

    $("#exam").submit( function() {
        return false;
});

 function clearInput() {

    $("#exam")[0].reset();
```

**PHP:**

```
$new_exam = $_POST['new_exam'];

$insert_exam = "insert into examination (exam_title) values ('$new_exam')";

$run_exam = mysqli_query($con, $insert_exam);
if($run_exam){
    echo "New Exam inserted";
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I did not get any error.

Comment: Does the exam.php only contain the form you provided? Or is there more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind events on dynamically created elements you have to bind the events on a parent of the element:

```
$('body').on('click', '#sub', function(){
    $.post($("#exam").attr("action"), $("#exam").serialize(), function(info){ $("#result").html(info); } );
    clearInput();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
});

$('body').on('submit', '#exam', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I use your code to envelope all my jquery code, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Oponjous Take a look at my update. Did you do it this way?

Comment: @Oponjous You welcome :) Kindly mark as the answer please.

Comment: @Oponjous Simply click on the check on the left of the answer under the upvote/downvote arrows.